# unclosed quotation mark before the character string')'. I get this error

Tags: vb6

```
(   db.Execute "insert into Studentstemp(StudentNameA,FacultyNumber,DepartmentNumber" & _
",BatchDescription,programNumber, Studentstatus, Gender, AddmissionFormNo, StudentNumber)values('" & VBA.Trim(TxtStudentNameA.Text) & "','" & _
                                                              CmbFaculty.BoundText & "','" & _
                                                              CmbDepartMent.BoundText & "','" & _
                                                              CmbBatch.BoundText & "','" & _
                                                              CmbProgram.BoundText & "','" & _
                                                              Cmbastatute.Text & "','" & _
                                                              CmbGnder.Text & "','" & _
                                                              TxtStudyFees.Text & ")")
```

Comment: You're doing SQL completely wrong; imagine if one of your strings had an apostrophe in it. Use [parameters](http://www.vb6.us/forums/%5Bcatpath%5D/how-do-i-create-parameter-sql-query-vb6).

Answer (score 2):

You missed one ' at the end.

```
(db.Execute "insert into Studentstemp(StudentNameA,FacultyNumber,DepartmentNumber" & _
            ",BatchDescription,programNumber, Studentstatus, Gender, AddmissionFormNo" & _
            ",StudentNumber)values('" & VBA.Trim(TxtStudentNameA.Text) & "','" & _
             CmbFaculty.BoundText & "','" & CmbDepartMent.BoundText & "','" & _
             CmbBatch.BoundText & "','" & CmbProgram.BoundText & "','" & _
             Cmbastatute.Text & "','" & CmbGnder.Text & "','" & TxtStudyFees.Text & "')")
```

Answer (score 1):

What dour high arch is telling you is that you will get this error if one of the strings that get input in your program has an apostrophe in it.  To prove this to yourself, enter the student name "O'Malley" in txtStudentName.  Now, I agree that you should use parameters, but to fix this particular problem, you'll need to do this:

```
...values('" & _
    Replace(Trim(txtStudentName.Text), "'", "''") & "','" & _
    Replace(CmbFaculty.BoundText, "'", "''") & "','" & _
    Replace(CmbDepartMent.BoundText, "'", "''") & "','" & _
...
```

and so on.  SQL takes two apostrophes to mean a literal apostrophe, so `'O''Malley'` would be the way to enter the value O'Malley in a field in SQL.